# How to create new user using AWS SDK for PHP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know how to create new user using AWS Console but is there an a way to do the same via PHP SDK?

AWS Create New User

Actually I want to create users with SDK to apply permissions (limited access to folders). There will a folder for each user in a bucket, user will be able to access only allotted folder.

So in short my script will be doing this

create AWS user
create folder in a bucket for the user created in step#1
Grant access to folder create in step#2 to user created in step#1
After this happens, another script running on another website will allow logged in user to access his/her own folder. So no user will be able to see other user's folder.

Is this possible with AWS?